# Photoshop eyedropper automatically copy color

Tags: photoshop

Is there an option or something that I can do to automatically copy color (hex) picked from eyedropper in CS6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the eyedropper tool right-click and select "Copy Color's HEX Code" from the context menu.

Comment: Personally I feel that even though " eyedropper tool right-click Copy Color" works well still if you make keyboard shortcut 1) then you just need to use keyboard shortcut blindly after picking color using eye dropper 2) this will save your right click and select hex color two actions :) any thoughts on this

Comment: You're right, and what I *really* wish I could do is just hold a modifier key while clicking on a color to copy it.

Comment: exactly that would be great :)

Answer (score 10):

Please find below steps, basically you need to define keyboard shortcut

1. Pick color using eyedropper it will appear as foreground color
2. Goto Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > " Shortcuts for " select drop down, select "Panel Menus"
3. Scroll down to panel menu command to open "color"
4. Inside Copy colors hex code you can specify shortcut example `Shift + Ctrl + 1` press OK
5. Now press that shortcut and hit `ctrl + v` in notepad or favorite text editor

Comment: Great answer. I'd recommend this over the 'copy color html' option, since it is more flexible, and the copy color html seems to only ever copy color="#ffffff" which is useless for background colors. I wish photoshop was context sensitive and could tell if the color was sampled from text or backgrounds, but alas.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on where you are trying to copy the colour to? Once you have used the colour dropper the hexidecimel number is displayed, which could be copied and pasted?

Comment: I want to copy it to clipboard...
I want pick a color and then in eg. Sublime press CTRL+V to get this color hex...

Answer (score 0):

Select the color you want with the eyedropper and double click on the *Color Picker*. There you will find your selected color's RGB,CMYK,HSB...etc values. At the bottom you will find the hex value of your color.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question at all. they're asking how to automatically copy it (to the clipboard i assume)

Answer (score 0):

You click on Color Sampler Tool to pick Color.
Then you can see the required color in CMYK, RGB, Greyscale, HSB, Total Ink, Hex code for website etc in Info (you need to press `F8` to activate info)